# How to make CDN or a way to speed up website loading

Tags: performance, cdn, pagespeed

I have a server from hostgator, the server is located in America and it gives 30ms to America region but outside that it gives 200 above ms and loads the site 10x slower than it loads in America, I was wondering if there's a way I can speed the loading, I heard something about CDN but not sure how that works, but what I something in my mind but I don't know how I can accomplish it, basically, I was thinking of getting a VPS from another region, for instance, lets say Australia, then can I make that a rally point or something with which if the users are from near that region it loads the site through that VPS but fast.

I'm open to new stuff. My site uses WordPress and gets lots of traffic, so if it's a VPS then what config is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using an actual CDN? The prices are cheaper than you think and will probably cost you less than spinning up multiple VPS's in other regions.

I use [Rackspace CDN](http://www.rackspace.co.uk/cdn) on my blog and it is really affordable (I pay less than a dollar a month) and I get coverage worldwide. Plus a CDN is configured to deliver assets as quickly as possible!

There are quite a few other CDNs out there and all are really competitively priced:

- [Google's CDN](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/cdn)
- [Amazon Cloudfront](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/)
- [Azure CDN](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/cdn/)

Answer (score 1):

What you describe is the normal increase of latency over distance. A CDN is exactly what you are looking for if you want to have a fast loading website in different geographical regions. The CDN will commonly pull or fetch the assets from your origin server and cache them on the servers which are close to your end users. The content is then delivered from a server very close to your visitors, which means less physical distance. This will decrease latency and improves round trip time (RTT), which makes your site fast around the globe.

I don't recommend to develop a CDN yourself and as this is a lot of maintenance and optimization work. I suggest to [compare CDN providers](http://cdncomparison.com) and chose the one that fits your needs (pricing, locations, technology, etc).